# Has the Hamiltonian Path Integral Been Made Rigorous?

Tags: lebesgue-integral, quantum-mechanics, wiener-measure

It is well known that the Lagrangian formulation of the path integral has been made rigorous, via the Wiener measure and/or the Trottier product formula. I haven't seen mathematicians discuss the hamiltonian version though, where one integrates over paths in phase space instead. Physicists seem to use it, but has it been made rigorous?

Comment: I wonder if this question could be acceptable for [MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/) too...